# How to make sure only one instance of a C kernel module is running (Singleton)?

Tags: c, design-patterns, kernel, singleton

For my assignment I need to determine suitable design patterns for my kernel module. Since it modifies one critical area of kernel code, I can't allow there to be more than one instance of it running - the modified code could be taken for the original and there'd be no way to restore the system to its initial state on module_exit. With that in mind, I chose the Singleton design pattern, among others. Now I need to actually implement the restriction, which goes along with it - the program needs to guarantee that only one instance of it is active at the time.

Is this common practice for kernel modules? I haven't seen this being discussed. If so, how can I implement the restriction?

Comment: Usually, a linux kernel module is identified by its name and can be loaded only once anyway; insmod will refuse to load it a second time

Answer (score 1):

it is not so much the number of instances of a module running, as it is multiple threads running that are executing that same module.

One way to avoid a conflict is to 'lock' a mutex, thereby blocking all other threads that are trying to execute that same code during some critical section of code, then 'unlocking' that mutex, thereby enabling another thread to execute that same code.